# How do I set a dropdown in excel to populate different data in cells below based upon the option selected from the dropdown?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am attempting to clean up a spreadsheet that we have that tells us what permissions to grant for certain roles in our ticketing system.

I have used the Data Validation tool to create my dropdown list.

The next step is where I am stuck. I would like to be able to select "Role A" from the dropdown and have a list populated in the cells below with the permissions.

I have a table on a separate tab in which the Headers equals the Roles and the permissions are listed below.

Everything I've researched says I should use VLOOKUP but I'm not sure that's the solution for what I am trying to do. I tried to attach screenshots but I guess I don't have enough points or something. I'm not an excel expert so thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have a drop-down in **A1** to select either *cat* or *dog* or *fruit*.

We put the lists in columns **C** through **E**

[image]

Then in **A2** enter:

```
=IF(A$1="dog",INDEX(D:D,ROWS($1:1)),IF(A$1="fruit",INDEX(C:C,ROWS($1:1)),IF(A$1="cat",INDEX(E:E,ROWS($1:1)))))
```

and copy down:

[image]